# How to run node.js app multiple times with different arguments in command line

Tags: node.js, linux

I need to start node.js app multiple times (200-300 times) with different arguments. Like so:

```
node index.js ABC
node index.js DEF
...
node index.js XYZ
```

What is the best approach to achieve that?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1. put all your arguments line by line in `params.txt` :

   ABC

   DEF

   GHI

   ...

   XYZ
2. RUN `cat params.txt | while read -r param; do node index.js $param; done`

The script above read the file line by line and pass it to your js script

Comment: how to run all node process in parallel ?

Comment: @Udhaya since all processes are started almost at the same time, and they actually run in a parallel way.