# Run node.js script multiple times with multiple command line arguements on windows

Tags: javascript, node.js, command-line-arguments

I have a script named `index.js` which I need to run with multiple command line arguements, one at a time. Something like this:

```
node index.js ABC
node index.js DEF
.
.
node index.js XYZ
```

So I have written all these arguements in a params.txt file, one on each line. In [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48262385/how-to-run-node-js-app-multiple-times-with-different-arguments-in-command-line) question, the solution for my problem is given, but it would not work on windows. Can anyone tell me what script I need to run on windows to achieve what is being done in the linked question?

Thank You.

Comment: if i'm not wrong, windows command line got `for` - `do` pair.

Comment: Yeah, what @BagusTesa said. You want `for /F` - sadly, my Windows machine is at work, but ss64 has all the answers: https://ss64.com/nt/for_f.html

Comment: but cat command is not available on windows, right?

Answer (score 0):

Try this

In a .bat file:

```
FOR /F %%i in ( params.txt ) do (
    call node index.js %%i
)
```

Or just from the command line this'll probably work:

```
FOR /F %i in ( params.txt ) do call node index.js %i
```

Note that if you stick it in a batch file (e.g. `runthemall.bat`) you need to double up the `%` signs.